# Comparison of refractive index of red and blue coloured light

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

My text book gives $v/c$=refractive index as 1 of the formulas to calculate.

Now,

\begin{eqnarray}
v({\rm red}) &>& v({\rm violet})  ~~~\mbox{and let glass be the medium} \\
\frac{v({\rm red})}{c} &>& \frac{v({\rm violet})}{c} \\
\mbox{Refractive index (red)} &>&  \mbox{Refractive index of (violet) }
\end{eqnarray}

But according to Cauchy's  equation

$$
R_i(\text{in a medium}) =R_i(\text{in vacuum}) + \frac{A}{\text{(wave length)}^2}
$$

According to this, red is having maximum wavelength and hence minimum refractive index.

This is contradicting. Please some one tell me where I am wrong. Thank you

Comment: What is $R_i$? what is $\nu$? What is $A$?

Comment: @Mauricio $v$ speed, $R_i$ refractive index

Comment: The refractive index is $n=c/v$ (if the $v$ is the speed of light in the medium and $c$ the speed of light in vacuum). Hence n>=1. So $v_{red}>v_{violet}$ implies $n_{red}<n_{violet}$

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is a typo in your book. The refractive index is usually a decreasing function of wavelength. For example, this is the refractive index for [BK7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_glass_(optics)) ([source](https://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=glass&book=BK7&page=SCHOTT))

[image]

This means

$$
v_{\color{red}{\rm red}} {\bf <} v_{\color{blue}{\rm blue}}
$$

Comment: But, from the ratio of velocity l